# how to validate text value from jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a modal popup. In which, two fields are present, Received Quantity and Total Quantity.
If any person type Received Quantity then from jquery it validates with Total Quantity.

**Total Quantity is coming from database. And it is hidden.**

- **condition1:** Received Quantity should not be greater than from Total Quantity.
- **condition2:** Received Quantity should not be less than 1.
- **condition3:** Received Quantity should not be in decimal. It only should be 
          integer.

```js
$("#update-receivings").click(function() {

  var received_quantity1 = $.trim($('#received_quantity').val());
  var total_quantity1 = $.trim($('#total_quantity').val());
  var intRegex = /^[1-9]\d*$/;

  if (received_quantity1 > total_quantity1) {
    alert('bad>');
    $('.error1').show();
    $('.error2').hide();
    $('#received_quantity1').val('');

  } else if (received_quantity1 < '1') {
    alert('bad<');
    $('.error1').show();
    $('.error2').hide();
    $('#received_quantity1').val('');
  } else if (!received_quantity1.match(intRegex)) {
    alert('badr');
    $('.error2').show();
    $('.error1').hide();
    $('#received_quantity1').val('');
  } else {
    alert('good');
    //$('#drug-receive-form').submit();
  }


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" id="drug-receive-form">
  <div class="modal-body">
    <!--<div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                           <input type="password" name="supply_code" id="supply_code" class="form-control">
        <span class="text-red" id="otp-error"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>-->
    <input type="hidden" name="total_quantity" id="total_quantity"> Received Quantity:&nbsp;<input type="text" name="received_quantity" id="received_quantity"><br>
    <span class="error1" style="color: Red; display: none">* Received Quantity Should not be greater than Available Quantity and should not less than 1</span>
    <span class="error2" style="color: Red; display: none">* Loose Quantity is not acceptable.</span>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <div class="text-left">
      <!--<button type="button" name="update-receivings" id="update-receivings" class="btn btn-info">Submit</button>-->
      <button type="button" name="update-receivings" id="update-receivings" class="btn btn-info">Yes  </button>
      <!--<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>--->
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Not Now </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

It is not working. If **Total Quantity is 45** and I type **Received Quantity 5.5**  then it is going in first condition. It matches 5.5 greater than 45.

Comment: convert your value to integer like var received_quantity1 = parseInt(received_quantity1 ); May be because of string comparision not work well.

Comment: But if I will type 5.5 than it will take 5 and I dont want. After that how it will check with regx?

Comment: I also need, if any person type in decimal than message should come "Loose Quantity is not acceptable"

Comment: Why do you use regex at all? If you want `5.5` your regex does not match, you would need a more complex one. Validation must be done server-side. Client-side validation is only usefull to reduce traffic, you may not rely on it. Consider using form field attributes to restrict inputs. `<input type="number" step="0.5" name="..."><input type="number" step="0.1" name="...">` Don't reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

use parseInt javascript function to compare numbers.

```
var received_quantity1 = parseInt($.trim($('#received_quantity').val()));
var total_quantity1 = parseInt($.trim($('#total_quantity').val()));
```

Comment: this is merely a comment not a concrete answer

Comment: But if I will type 5.5 than it will take 5 and I dont want. After that how it will check with regx?

Comment: I also need, if any person type in decimal than message should come "Loose Quantity is not acceptable"

Comment: you have validate entering text on input can not be entered if i.e. float numbers

Comment: I tried with this. But my second and third condition is not working.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: received_quantity1.match is not a function

Comment: I don't want float numbers. Means If any one insert float number than it should be an error. Condition 3 regx.

Comment: $(document).on('input', '.Numeric', function () {
                                this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9'\]/g, '');
                            });  use this

Answer (score 0):

Because first you have to check regular expression if it match than check other conditions, change sequence of your conditions.

```
<script>
$( "#update-receivings" ).click(function() {
var received_quantity1 = $.trim($('#received_quantity').val());
var total_quantity1 = $.trim($('#total_quantity').val());
var intRegex = /^[1-9]\d*$/;
 if(!received_quantity1.match(intRegex)){
        alert('badr');
    $('.error2').show();
    $('.error1').hide();
    $('#received_quantity1').val('');
    }
    else{
        alert('good');
            if( received_quantity1 > total_quantity1 )
              {
                alert('bad>');
                 $('.error1').show();
               $('.error2').hide();
               $('#received_quantity1').val('');

             }
            else if( received_quantity1 < '1' )
             {
               alert('bad<');
               $('.error1').show();
               $('.error2').hide();
               $('#received_quantity1').val('');
              }
              else{
                 $('#drug-receive-form').submit();
              }

    } 



 });
  </script>
```

Comment: Thank you. It is working now. But why regx should be first?

Comment: total_quantity1  is 70.00 and received_quantity1 is between 1 to 7. Then it is working. But if received_quantity1 is 8 or more than 8. Then it goes with received_quantity1 > total_quantity1

Answer (score 0):

**I found my answer this way:**

```
<script>
$( "#update-receivings" ).click(function() {
var received_quantity1 = parseInt($.trim($('#received_quantity').val()));
var total_quantity1 = parseInt($.trim($('#total_quantity').val()));
var received_quantity2 = $.trim($('#received_quantity').val());

 if(received_quantity1 != received_quantity2){
        //alert('badr');
    $('.error2').show();
    $('.error1').hide();
    $('#received_quantity2').val('');
    }
    else{
            if( received_quantity1 > total_quantity1 )
              {
                //alert('bad>');
                 $('.error1').show();
               $('.error2').hide();
               $('#received_quantity2').val('');

             }
            else if( received_quantity1 < '1' )
             {
               //alert('bad<');
               $('.error1').show();
               $('.error2').hide();
               $('#received_quantity2').val('');
              }
              else{
                  //alert('good');
                 $('#drug-receive-form').submit();
              }

    } 



 });

</script>
```